# How to load Yocto generated U-boot binaries to t1042d4rdb board

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, yocto, bitbake, u-boot

I created linux and U-boot images for NXP t1042d4rdb board using Yocto (using bitbake fsl-image-full command) on Ubuntu 16.04.6 . In my `"yocto sdk directory"/"build directory"/tmp/deploy/images/t1042d4rdb` directory, I have linux images and many binaries for u-boot (like u-boot.bin, u-boot-sdcard.bin, u-boot-nor.bin, u-boot-spi.bin ....). 
[you can see my /tmp/deploy/images/t1042d4rdb file here](https://i.hizliresim.com/vap54m.png)

I attached my UART serial converter to /dev/ttyUSB0 using minicom and wrote this command (found it on nxp forum)

```
"sudo dd if=u-boot.bin of=/dev/ttyUSB0 obs=4066 seek=1; sync"
```

nothing happened. Console messages from `"dmesg"` command

```
[ 4103.366033] ftdi_sio 3-4:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[ 4103.366053] usb 3-4: Detected FT232RL
[ 4103.370147] usb 3-4: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB
```

I am new at Yocto and U-boot. My question is, how can I load U-boot linux binaries to my board. Thanks for answers and any other suggestions.

Comment: The block size of 4066 is not a multiple of 512. At least this value seems to be wrong. Should it be 4096?

Comment: Result did not change. I am not even sure that am i checking right place for console messages or not. Do you have any idea how can I reach output messages of U-boot.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot write serial port device (ttyUSB0) directly with dd despite it is not show any error your written data probably disappears because ttyUSB0 device just a communication device.

On Yocto build directory (tmp/deploy/images) you can probably find an .sdcard image file or an .wic image which is combined Linux kernel, U-Boot and Rootfs images. So you need to write this image to related block device that you will use as boot device. In this case you can write this image like this; "dd if= of=/dev/your-sd-card-device bs=1M sync".

I hope it will help your problem.

Comment: My file structure is like this https://i.hizliresim.com/vap54m.png. Is u-boot-sdcard.bin the file we seek ?

Comment: I think you need to configure your Yocto environment to output the .sdcard file. You can check this link to learn how to prepare sdcard image, I think this process is similar for any processors.(https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-334664)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll try it. Isn't there any way to load u-boot from serial port to boards nand,nor, spi or other memories ?

Comment: You can use tftp protocol but to do this you need already installed U-Boot image. Serial port mostly used for the terminal interface.

Comment: I researched my boards documentation. It seems only u-boot-///-.bin files are available for the SDK I used for building Yocto images and U-boot images. It does not create any .img file for u-boot but it seems .bin files are enought to port U-boot. For now, the only problem is how can I port U-boot binaries to my boards memory without using an SDCARD. Thanks for your answers by the way.